# Can you connect 2 Linux machines using GRE without dealing with router configuration?

Tags: networking

I've tried looking for how to connect my Linux machines over the Internet to sort of create a point to point VPN for a project. Both are located physically in different cities, behind a NAT. For what I'm testing, unfortunately I can't be touching any router, max I can perform is port forwarding.

Is there any way to create such a setup with only 2 port forwarded machines, each behind NAT and have a dynamic IP(obviously xD)?

I want a GRE tunnel because I can then use the interface for my purposes, and from what I can see its pretty straightforward.

Comment: try to see if ngrok can help you.

Comment: Is that a DDNS solution?

Comment: you mention that you can not do a port forwarding, a DDNS solution is not going to help if it point to your public ip because you can't do a port forward.

Comment: So I'm doing this in order to access my OpenStack install, which i don't think will work with ngrok since it assigns a domain instead of the endpoint IP :(